# GNU make: Execute target but take dependency from file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want the rules of a target to be executed but all dependent targets shall regard this target as satisfied.

How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
$(NETWORK_SHARE)/foo.log:
    @echo Warning: server offline, still continue ...
    @exit 0

foo.csv: $(NETWORK_SHARE)/foo.log
    @echo Long export from a (different) server
    @echo sleep 20
    @echo foo > $@
```

If $(NETWORK_SHARE)/foo.log exists: foo.csv shall be rebuilt if $(NETWORK_SHARE)/foo.log is newer than foo.csv; otherwise **nothing** should happen (default)

If $(NETWORK_SHARE)/foo.log does not exist (e.g., server offline, failure, ...) only a message indicating a problem should be printed but foo.csv shall only be built if foo.csv does not exist.

I played around with .PHONY and returning different return values but for case 2, the expensive "export" happens as soon as I execute something on $(NETWORK_SHARE)/foo.log ...

Regards
divB

Comment: I know of no clean way to do this, but you could kludge it with conditionals withing the commands...

Comment: Hi, Thank you this is what I do already, however, I have still the problem. I think I found a good way to re-formulate:

_I want to output a message (execute commands) on a target which is up to date_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, thanks to [Thiton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847601/thiton) answer in my related question ([Force make to find out-of-date condition from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121000/force-make-to-find-out-of-date-condition-from-file)) I can now provide a hack to solve this:

```
.PHONY: always-remake

NETWORK_SHARE = //server/dfs/common/logs

.PHONY: all
all: foo.csv

# file does not exist ...
ifeq "$(wildcard $(NETWORK_SHARE)/foo.log)" ""

old_file: always-remake
    @echo Warning: network is not available ....

foo.csv: old_file
    @echo Expensive export
    @sleep 10
    @echo $@ > $@
else
foo.csv: $(NETWORK_SHARE)/foo.log
    @echo Doing expensive export since log file changed ...
    @sleep 10
    @echo $@ > $@
endif
```

"old_file" is a dummy file which **must** exist and should never be newer than any other file (e.g. 1/1/1971, 00:00)

Regards
divB

Answer (score 1):

Looks like instead of using some old file (that someone can accidentally touch), you can use an order-only prerequisite. Here's a quote from the GNU makefile manual (chapter 4.3)

> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a
>   specific ordering on the rules to be invoked without forcing the
>   target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case,
>   you want to define order-only prerequisites. Order-only prerequisites
>   can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (|) in the prerequisites
>   list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol are normal; any
>   prerequisites to the right are order-only:
>
> ```
>  targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites
> ```