# Force make to find out-of-date condition from file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

(this is similar to [GNU make: Execute target but take dependency from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104681/gnu-make-execute-target-but-take-dependency-from-file) but slightly different).

When I try to force to build a target, make automatically thinks that this target is out of date and forces a run of all targets which depend on it.

In my case, the target is a recursive make call which does a lot of work and might just return with "nothing to be done":

```
 .PHONY: intermediate.dat
 intermediate.dat:
      $(MAKE) expensive_chain_which_finally_creates_intermediate.dat

 step1.dat: intermediate.dat
      sleep 10
 
 step2.dat: step1.dat
      sleep 15
 
 step3.dat: step2.dat
      sleep 10

 all: step3.dat
      sleep 5
```

In this case, "make all" runs for 40 seconds although intermediate.dat might not have changed (recursive make returned "nothing to be done"). However, *if* the recursive make updated intermediate.dat, the target shall be out of date.

Is there really no way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `intermediate.dat` *depend* on a phony target instead of being phony itself.

```
 .PHONY : always-remake

 intermediate.dat : always-remake
```

IIRC, the last time I solved the problem, the .PHONY didn't work as intended and I used:

```
 always-remake :
     @true
```

instead. However, I can't recall why, so try the .PHONY first.

The problem with making `intermediate.dat` itself phony is that `make` **never checks the existence/date of a phony file**, which is behaviour that you want. You only need to trigger the rebuild rule, which is done by a prerequisite that is out of date; a phony prerequisite is always out of date, so it does the job.

Comment: Unbelievable! I just wanted to write that I have tried already but then I created another minimum example, tried out and it worked! Both of your proposals. Thank you very much! Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: @divB: Updated with short explanation.

Comment: This works because depending on a `.PHONY` target will always run the tasks which depend on it, because of the way [Make handles `.PHONY` targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets).  However, it will not skip the time expensive code in the dependent task.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is to use an [***order-only*** prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types), plus a recursive call to `make`.  This can be useful when you want to implement some additional logic around when the `intermediate.dat` file needs to be created, or when you want to decouple a target from the usual `exists && newer than` check that `make` does.

#### For example:

Let's say that the file contains some date-sensitive material that subsequent tasks depend on, and that it expires after **12 hours**.  We only want to recreate the file when any of these is true:

- The file is older than 12 hours
- The file does not exist

To implement the make target & recipes, we'll create a `.PHONY` `check-intermediate.dat` target, which runs the time check, conditionally removes the file if it's expired, and then re-runs `make` for that file.

Note that the `check-intermediate.dat` target will be defined via the [*order-only* prerequisite syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types) (e.g. `intermediate.dat: | check-intermediate.dat`) which causes it to run always before the target (e.g. `intermediate.dat`).  The time check is inexpensive, and we always want it to run and manage the file for us, but not invalidate the original `make` check on `intermediate.dat` if it already exists like a [normal prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types) `.PHONY` target would.

```
 .PHONY: check-intermediate.dat
 check-intermediate.dat:
    if [ -e intermediate.dat ]; then  find intermediate.dat -mmin +720 -exec bash -c 'rm -f "{}"; $(MAKE) intermediate.dat' \; ; fi

 intermediate.dat: | check-intermediate.dat
    echo run-expensive-tasks-here-to-create-intermediate.dat
 step1.dat: intermediate.dat
    sleep 10

 step2.dat: step1.dat
    sleep 15

 step3.dat: step2.dat
    sleep 10

 all: step3.dat
    sleep 5
```

Now, anything that depends on the `intermediate.dat` target will first run the check, remove the file if it's expired, and re-run `make intermediate.dat` before running the rest of the dependent targets.  If the `intermediate.dat` file already exists, it will run the check, and if the check passes, it will continue without running the time expensive recreation task.

The problem with depending on a `.PHONY` target is that it will **always** run the tasks which depend on it, because of the way [GNU Make handles `.PHONY` targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets).  This can cause the `make` run to always perform the time expensive operations even when it does not need to:

> A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if it is, its recipe will be run every time make goes to update that file. As long as a phony target is never a prerequisite of a real target, the phony target recipe will be executed only when the phony target is a specified goal (see Arguments to Specify the Goals).